# The ControlID property must be set on the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this code apsx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateTable" runat="server" Text="Actualizar" Visible="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnGraph" runat="server" Text="Gráfico" Visible="False" PostBackUrl="ShowGraph.aspx" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Excel" Visible="False" />
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000"/>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr><td>
            <div style="width: 100%">

                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BorderColor="Silver"
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="1" CssClass="ttc"
                ForeColor="Silver" HorizontalAlign="Left" AllowPaging="True" PageIndex="1">
                <PagerSettings LastPageImageUrl="~/Images/arrow_end.gif" PreviousPageImageUrl="~/Images/arrow_left.gif" FirstPageImageUrl="~/Images/arrow_beg.gif" Position="Top" NextPageImageUrl="~/Images/arrow_right.gif" Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"></PagerSettings>
                <RowStyle CssClass="ttc"></RowStyle>
                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="ttcs"></SelectedRowStyle>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="ttc"></PagerStyle>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="thc"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:GridView> 
        </div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlLabelValues" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExcel" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and I got the following message when I try to go on web site;

> *The ControlID property must be set on the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*
>
> *Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The ControlID property must be set on the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.*
>
> *An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.*

and I can't find the solution!

Can any one help me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must use triggers as follow:

```
 <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpApplicationMeqsed" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
 </Triggers>
```

You foggot write event name and you should use **AsyncPostBackTrigger**

For example this is a real usage of trigger:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updGoal" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table id="appEnterForm:selectMenus">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="drpApplicationGoal">
                            The goal of application</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpApplicationGoal" runat="server" Width="498px" ClientIDMode="Static"
                            AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpApplicationGoal_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpApplicationGoal" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote event name?

Comment: And please rename uplaodpanel id, because some exception render when use default id.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the btnExcel is set to Visible="false", when false then it isn't rendered to the page at all.  but your  section is going to look for a control named btnExcel, but this doesn't exist...